# wxPython validator not called for grandchild of dialogue

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I have something like this:

```
class ADialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        self.editor = APanel(parent=self)
        ...
    ...

class APanel(wx.Panel):
    def CreatePanel(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        self.textCtrls = []
        for (key, val) in zip(foo, bar):
            ...
            box = wx.TextCtrl(parent=self, value=val, validator=Validator())
            ....
```

Now, I *need* to have APanel seperate, because the text controls have to be changed dynamically.

Problem is, the `Validate()` method of `Validator` never gets called.

I've tried passing the flag `wx.WS_EX_VALIDATE_RECURSIVELY` to `wx.Dialog.__init__`, and also tried overriding the `Validate()` method of ADialog to call `Validate()` on APanel, and then overridden the `Validate()` method of APanel to call the validators of each text control, but that didn't work either.

os: Windows 7
python version: 2.5.4
wxPython version: 2.8.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wx.WS_EX_VALIDATE_RECURSIVELY is an extended style, so you need to set it with SetExtraStyle, not by passing it to the base class' __init__